# JavaScript: using callbacks to control program flow

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I'm still trying to get oriented with JS, and have recently had a lot of trouble understanding the role of callbacks.

I can see that callbacks offer a more asynchronous(?) way of returning values generated in a function. For example, this makes sense to me:

```
function summation (a, b, _callback) {
 if (typeof(_callback) === 'function') {
  _callback(a+b);
 }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
 summation(2,3,function (_val) {
  console.log(_val);
 }
});
```

As opposed to something like `var _val = summation(2,3);` Where `var` isn't available immediately following the assignment.

I have difficulty making this process scale as I attempt to manipulate elements on a webpage with jQuery. I have an object which tracks elements:

```
function createObj (_callback) {
 var test = new Object();
 test.mainPane = $('#mainPane');
 if (typeof(_callback) === 'function') {
  _callback(test);
 }
}
```

If I wish to pass `test.mainPane` into a function `fitToPage()` which adjusts the properties of the element to fit a given screen size, and then want to pass the element to another function `createElems()` which adds children to the element, things begin to fall apart:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 createObj(function (test) {
  fitToPage(test, function (test) {
   createElems(test, null);
  });
 });
});
```

And it only seems to get worse if I try avoiding this callback hell(?) by creating special functions which do nothing but help me manage the callbacks to other functions. I'm confident that I've missed something important, but haven't come up with the correct search terms to find it. Is there a better method?

Comment: Use promises. http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns/

Comment: What's the purpose of having callback in your summation function? Why it cannot be just `function summation(a,b) { return a + b; }` ?

Comment: @c-smile: I suspect that was just to demonstrate how callbacks work.  Replace summation by an actual asynchronous process...

Comment: @ScottSauyet asynchronous cases (a.k.a. event handlers) is where callbacks are primarily used. I do not see any asynchronous code in his/her samples other than document.ready event handler so asking - what's the purpose of callbacks there?

Comment: @SLaks, Thank you! Your blog post appears to address my issue exactly. The next chance I get I will play with implementing promises.

Comment: @c-smile, Thank you; my intent was to show a trivialization for the sake of a sample, but I believe you have pointed out another disparity in my understanding. I assumed all assignments and function calls in JS were asynch in the same sense as an assembly pipelined operation, meaning that any value returned from a function wouldn't land in its assigned variable until a few lines later.. I'm going to look into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've run across one of the main issues involved in using callbacks to work with asynchronous code.  Asynchronicity is contagious.  Once you start to use it in one spot, the surrounding code also needs it, and then the code around that, and so on.

One of the more popular ways to deal with this at the moment is [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).  These don't actually eliminate the callback issues, but they let you deal with them in a simpler manner syntactically.  The idea is that instead of accepting a callback, a function returns an object to which the caller can attach a callback that will be processed later.  In the promise libraries, these object must expose a `then` method that takes a `success` and an `error` callback.   I don't know if jQuery's `ready` method exposes it, so this might not be quite right, but it should be close to how you would rework your example with Promises:

```
$(document).ready()
    .then(createObj)
    .then(fitToPage)
    .then(function(test) {return createElems(test, null)});
```

And if you have a version of `createElems` that partially applied the `null`, then that last line could simply be

```
    .then(createElems2);
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript execution model is synchronous by design.  So if you have function call in code the function body will be executed immediately, synchronously and without interruption by other tasks. Therefore this

```
function summation(a,b) {
  return a + b;
}
var r = summation(1,2); // -> 3
```

will be executed as it is written.

At the same time you can ask browser runtime environment to call [back] your function (callback per se) when some event will happen. Therefore your function will be called asynchronously:

```
function doSomethingWhenDocumentIsLoaded() 
{
  // document ready, do something with it.
}

$(document).ready(doSomethingWhenDocumentIsLoaded);
```

Here we defined function and asked the runtime to call that function back when the document will be loaded/ready for operation.

Comment: Thanks again @c-smile, you've answered a question I didn't realize I had.